# SMTP server keeps timing out when I try to send mail from Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, smtp

I am using Charter.net as my email account and can send from the website but not from Thunderbird.

I have no proxy and I have all security settings to none.

What could be the problem?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities.

1. If you have antivirus installed with outboud email scanning, try disabling this.
2. Increase the tcptimout value. You don't mention which version of thunderbird you are using and the method used to perform this task has changed with later additions. That aside [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Modify_Thunderbird_settings) are the general guidelines. Try increasing the value for 'mailnews.tcptimeout' perhaps even as far as 1200.